# Binning frequency distribution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have data in the two lists *value* and *freq* like this:

```
value freq
1      2
2      1
3      3
6      2
7      3
8      3
....
```

and I want the output to be

```
bin freq
1-3   6
4-6   2
7-9   6
...
```

I can write few lines of code to do this. However, I am looking if there are builitin functions in standard python or Numpy? I found the solution when you are given data in array/list with repetition i.e. they are not already grouped into frequency table(eg.  `d= [1,1,2,3,3,3,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,...]`. However, in this case I could not find the answers. I do not want to convert my data into single expanded list like `d` first and use histogram function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
values = [1,2,3,6,7,8]
freqs = [2,1,3,2,3,3]

hist, _ = np.histogram(values, bins=[1, 4, 7, 10], weights=freqs)
print hist
```

output:

```
[6 2 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import collections
d=[1,1,2,3,3,3,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8]
collections.Counter([i-i%3+3 for i in d])
```

it would generate a dictionary with what you want.

Comment: my data is nut supplied the way you have taken d.. but as two different list of value and frequency. If it is given as d.. np.histogram works

Answer (score 0):

> I found the solution when you are given data in array/list with repetition

You didn't say what the solution was, but if it supports taking an iterator, you can *generate* it, instead of creating the entire list:

import itertools

```
values = [1,2,3,6]
freqs =  [2,1,3,2]

v_iter = itertools.chain(*[ itertools.repeat(v,f) for v, f in zip(values, freqs) ])

#for x in v_iter:
#    print x

your_solution(v_iter)
```