# Statistics / distributions over very large data sets

Tags: python, statistics

Looking at the discussions about simple statistics from a file of data, I wonder which of these techniques would scale best over very large data sets (~millions of entries, Gbytes of data).

Are numpy solutions that read entire data set into memory appropriate here?  See:

[Binning frequency distribution in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697350/binning-frequency-distribution-in-python/15697952#15697952)

Answer (score 1):

You are not telling which kind of data you haveand what you want to calculate!

If you have something that is or is easily converted into positive integers of moderate size (e.g., 0..1e8), you may use `bincount`. Here is an example of how to make a distribution (histogram) of the byte values of all bytes in a very large file (works up to whatever your file system can manage):

```
import numpy as np

# number of bytes to read at a time
CHUNKSIZE = 100000000

# open the file
f = open("myfile.dat", "rb")

# cumulative distribution array
cum = np.zeros(256)

# read through the file chunk by chunk
while True:
    chunkdata = np.fromstring(f.read(CHUNKSIZE), dtype='uint8')
    cum += np.bincount(chunkdata)
    if len(chunkdata < CHUNKSIZE):
        break
```

This is very fast, the speed is really limited by the disk access. (I got approximately 1 GB/s with a file in the OS cache.)

Of course, you may want to calculate some other statistics (standard deviation, etc.), but even then you can usually use the distributions (histograms) to calculate that statistics. However, if you do not need the distribution, then there may be even faster methods. Calculating the average is the same as just adding all values together.

If you have a text file, then the major challenge is in parsing the file chunk-by-chunk. The standard methods `loadtxt` and `csv` module are not necessarily very efficient with very large files.

If you have floating point numbers or very large integers, the method above does not work directly, but in some cases you may just use some bits of the FP numbers or round things to closest integer, etc. In any case the question really boils down to what kind of data you really have, and what statistics you want to calculate. There is no Swiss knife which would solve all statistics problems with huge files.

Reading the data into memory is a very good option if you have enough memory. In certain cases you can do it without having enough memory (use `numpy.memmap`). If you have a text file with 1 GB of floating point numbers, the end result may fit into less than 1 GB, and most computers can handle that very well. Just make sure you are using a 64-bit Python.